# r Shiny make textInput conditional on a previous selectInput

Tags: r, shiny, textinput, selectinput

Hello and sorry for what might be a basic Shiny question.

In my mini-Shiny app, I want the user to:

1. Pick a name from a list of pre-existing names using selectInput().
2. Only if the name s/he has in mind is not on the list, I'd like a new widget to appear where s/he should enter the name using textInput().

I am stuck - my verbatimTextOutput statements inside the mainPanel on the UI side are not working.

Thank you for your hints!

```
library(shiny)

ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("chosen_name", label = h4("Select one of the names:"))
    ),
    mainPanel(                       # Just shows what was selected
      # Next two lines don't work if uncommented:
      #  verbatimTextOutput('chosen_name')
      #  verbatimTextOutput("name_openend")
    )
  )
))

server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  # A vector of pre-existing names:
  mynames <- c("John", "Mary", "Jim")

  # Allow to select a name from the list of pre-existing names:
  output$chosen_name <- renderUI({
    selectInput('chosen_name',"Select a name:",
                choices = c("Name not on our list", mynames),
                selected = "Name not on our list")
  })

  # Open end box to enter name - if the name the user wants to enter is not on the list:
  output$name_openend <- renderUI({
    if (!output$chosen_name == 'Name not on our list') return(NULL) else {
      textInput("If the name you want is not on our list, type it here:")
    }
  })

})


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated Code

```
library(shiny)

ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("chosen_name", "select name", choices = ""),
      uiOutput("new")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("chosen")
    )
  )
))

server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  # A vector of pre-existing names:
  mynames <- c("John", "Mary", "Jim")

  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "chosen_name", label = "Select a name:", choices = c(mynames, "Name not on our list"))
  })

  # Open end box to enter name - if the name the user wants to enter is not on the list:
  output$new <- renderUI({
    if (!input$chosen_name == 'Name not on our list') return(NULL) else {
      textInput("Not_on_list", "If the name you want is not on our list, type it here:")
    }
  })
  #
  # 
  # Allow to select a name from the list of pre-existing names:

  output$chosen <- renderText({
    if (!input$chosen_name == 'Name not on our list') {
    return(paste("Chosen name:", input$chosen_name))
    }
    else {
      return(paste("Chosen name:", input$Not_on_list))
    }
  })

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you, Diego - this is very-very close to the solution I was looking for! Only one question: is it possible to show on the Main Panel only ONE output: if the name is taken from the list, then show it. But if the name was typed, then show the typed name (but separately from the input box)?

Comment: I think you can. You'll have to render whatever the user types back to mainpanel. But where would you like the input box in? In the sidebar panel or mainpanel?

Comment: The location of the input box doesn't really matter. The sidebar is good.

Comment: I updated code. I think this might be the behavior you are going for.

Comment: Thank you so much, Diego. It works beautifully! May I ask a question? Why do we have to use updateSelectInput here instead of just SelectInput?

Comment: I am not sure it's mandatory to use updateSelectInput. But I remember from the past that if I want my options in the dropdown list to be dependent on a file that a user inputs, then I need that function. That could be the case if you ever wanted to bring a long list of names from a text file to your app.

Answer (score 1):

You confused a bit the functions on the ui side:
If you use `renderUI()` on the server side, you will have to use `uiOutput()` on the ui side to make it work. Also you should avoid using the same id twice. Finally, for the textinput i added an id and a label.

**Full code reads:**

```
library(shiny)

ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("chosen_nm", label = h4("Select one of the names:"))
    ),
    mainPanel(                       # Just shows what was selected
      # Next two lines don't work if uncommented:
      uiOutput("name_openend")
    )
  )
))

server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  # A vector of pre-existing names:
  mynames <- c("John", "Mary", "Jim")

  # Allow to select a name from the list of pre-existing names:
  output$chosen_nm <- renderUI({
    selectInput('chosen_name',"Select a name:",
                choices = c("Name not on our list", mynames),
                selected = "Name not on our list")
  })

  output$chosen_name2 <- renderText({
    paste("The chosen name is: ", input$chosen_name)
  })

  # Open end box to enter name - if the name the user wants to enter is not on the list:
  output$name_openend <- renderUI({
    req(input$chosen_name)
    if (input$chosen_name == 'Name not on our list'){
      textInput("newName", "If the name you want is not on our list, type it here:")
    }else{
      verbatimTextOutput('chosen_name2')
    }
  })

})


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: for me there is only a warning, that existed before. You can add `    req(input$chosen_name)` to avoid that. Do you still have a warning/error after the update?

Answer (score 0):

There were a few things that I needed to cut out to make it work. First was the sidebarLayout. This might have been messing with your mainPanel. I am sure you can get this to work just make sure the mainPanel is in the right place and not being added to the sidebarLayout, which might have been the problem.

There were a few other problems like renderUI and UIOutput. Maybe someone else will add a post on how to use those functions. Also, I added a reactive function so the textOutput would change.

Take a look at how mine works.

```
mynames <- c("John", "Mary", "Jim")
ui = shinyUI(
  fluidPage(

    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput('chosen_name',"Select a name:",
                  choices = c("Name not on our list", mynames),
                  selected = "Name not on our list")
    ),
    mainPanel(   
      textOutput('chosen_name2')

    )
  )
)

server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  # A vector of pre-existing names:
  selectedchosen_name <- reactive({
    if (input$chosen_name == 'Name not on our list') {return("Pick a name")} else {
      return("If the name you want is not on our list, type it here:")
    }
  })

  # Allow to select a name from the list of pre-existing names:
  output$chosen_name2 <- renderText({
    selectedchosen_name()
  })

  # Open end box to enter name - if the name the user wants to enter is not on the list:


})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I removed some parts that might be redundant, but right now it's simplified so you can add to it. If you have any questions just ask.

Comment: Thank you very much, Kyle, but it's not working - it's showing just the pull-down on the left and nothing else but text on the right - no text box. BTW - the location of the controls (sidebar or main pain) doesn't really matter.

Comment: Yeah I didn't add a text box to type in. What do you want to happen when you type in the box? Do you want the name to be added to mynames after typing it?

Comment: If the name the user wants to enter is not among the names in the list, then an open-end box should open where the user types the name. And then the name should be returned on the main panel - no matter how that name was created - using a pull-down or using typing.