# r Shiny make multiple textInput conditional on a previous selectInput

Tags: r, shiny

This is based on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55483684/r-shiny-make-textinput-conditional-on-a-previous-selectinput) asked about R Shiny, but my goal is each time the user selects something different from the dropdown, different sliders appear.

Simply put, if the user selects Level A, then sliders AA, BB, and CC appear. If they select Level B, then sliders DD and EE appear. Lastly if they select Level C then FF, GG, HH, II appear.

My code is below, but I am not sure how to add multiple sliders. Any help is appreciated!

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(position = "left",
                sidebarPanel(
                  selectInput("level", 
                              "Level:",
                              choices = ''),
                  uiOutput("new"),
                  width=2),
                mainPanel()
  )) 

server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "level", label = "Level:", choices = c('A', 'B', 'C'))
  })
  
  output$new <- renderUI({
    if (!input$level == 'A') return(NULL) else {
      sliderInput("slider_aa", "AA:", min = 0, max = 90, value = 10)
      #sliderInput("slider_bb", "BB:", min = 0, max = 90, value = 10)
      #sliderInput("slider_cc", "CC:", min = 0, max = 90, value = 10)
    }
    
  })
  
})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

**EDIT:**
I found a solution, in part thanks to comments below!!!!

````
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(position = "left",
                sidebarPanel(
                  selectInput("level", 
                              "Level:",
                              choices = ''),
                  uiOutput("new"),
                  uiOutput("new1"),
                  uiOutput("new2"),
                  width=2),
                mainPanel()
  )) 

server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "level", label = "Level:", choices = c('A', 'B', 'C'))
  })
  
  output$new <- renderUI({
    
    #tagList(sliderInput("slider_aa", "AA:", min = 0, max = 90, value = 10), sliderInput("slider_bb", "BB:", min = 0, max = 90, value = 10))
    
    if (!input$level == 'A') return(NULL) else {
      tagList(sliderInput("slider_aa", "AA:", min = 0, max = 90, value = 10), 
              sliderInput("slider_bb", "BB:", min = 0, max = 90, value = 10))
      
    }
    
  })
  
  output$new1 <- renderUI({
    
    #tagList(sliderInput("slider_aa", "AA:", min = 0, max = 90, value = 10), sliderInput("slider_bb", "BB:", min = 0, max = 90, value = 10))
    
    if (!input$level == 'B') return(NULL) else {
      tagList(sliderInput("slider_cc", "CC:", min = 0, max = 90, value = 10), 
              sliderInput("slider_dd", "DD:", min = 0, max = 90, value = 10))
      
    }
    
  })
  
  output$new2 <- renderUI({
    
    #tagList(sliderInput("slider_aa", "AA:", min = 0, max = 90, value = 10), sliderInput("slider_bb", "BB:", min = 0, max = 90, value = 10))
    
    if (!input$level == 'C') return(NULL) else {
      tagList(sliderInput("slider_ee", "EE:", min = 0, max = 90, value = 10))
      
    }
    
  })
  
})

shinyApp(ui,server)```
````

Comment: To get a `renderUI()` to display multiple controls, wrap them in a `tagList()`: for example, `tagList(sliderInput("slider_aa", ...), sliderInput("slider_bb", "...))`.

Comment: You might also need `if (input$level != 'A')` instead of `if (!input$level == 'A')`...

Comment: Just use a series of `ifelse`s, as you have started to do, (or a `case_when`) to populate the `tagList` according to the value of `input$level`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add all in one single `renderUI`

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(position = "left",
                sidebarPanel(
                  selectInput("level", 
                              "Level:",
                              choices = ''),
                  uiOutput("new"),
                
                  width=2),
                mainPanel()
  )) 

server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "level", label = "Level:", choices = c('A', 'B', 'C'))
  })
  
  output$new <- renderUI({
    
    #tagList(sliderInput("slider_aa", "AA:", min = 0, max = 90, value = 10), sliderInput("slider_bb", "BB:", min = 0, max = 90, value = 10))
    
    if (input$level == 'A') {
      tagList(sliderInput("slider_aa", "AA:", min = 0, max = 90, value = 10), 
              sliderInput("slider_bb", "BB:", min = 0, max = 90, value = 10))
      
    } else if(input$level == 'B'){
      tagList(sliderInput("slider_cc", "CC:", min = 0, max = 90, value = 10), 
              sliderInput("slider_dd", "DD:", min = 0, max = 90, value = 10))
      
    } else if(input$level == 'C'){
      tagList(sliderInput("slider_ee", "EE:", min = 0, max = 90, value = 10))
      
    }
    
  })
  


})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```